# Calculate the double integral over a given general region

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $M$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded by the parabola $x^2$ and the lines $x = 2$ and $y = 0$.

I have to compute $I$ in two ways, where:
$$I = \iint_{M}xy\,dx\,dy$$

I rewrote $M$ first as a general region w.r.t $x$-axis and then w.r.t $y$-axis:
$$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, 0 \le x \le 2, \, 0 \le y \le x^2\}$$
$$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, 0 \le y \le 4, \, 0 \le x \le \sqrt y\}$$

Now, I calculated $I$ using these two writings of the set and got:
$$I = \int_0^2 \int_{0}^{x^2} xy \, dy \, dx = \frac{16}{3}$$
$$I = \int_0^4 \int_{0}^{\sqrt y} xy \, dx \, dy = \frac{32}{3}$$

Why are the results different? $M$ is the same set, but written in two ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second description of $M$:
$$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, 0 \le y \le 4, \, 0 \le x \le \sqrt y\}$$

is wrong.

It should be

$$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, 0 \le y \le 4, \, \color{red}{\sqrt y} \le x \le \color{red}2\}$$

Comment: Is there a method for transforming between the region w.r.t $y$-axis to the region w.r.t $x$-axis?

Comment: I usually just sketch out the region and describe the region. not aware of method to perform such transformation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the limits of second integral it should be $$I = \int_0^4 \int_{\sqrt y}^{2} xy \, dx \, dy=\frac{16}{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

The region described by$$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, 0 \le y \le 4, \, 0 \le x \le \sqrt y\}$$ is not the desired region. You need to change it to $$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, 0 \le y \le 4, \sqrt y\le x\le 2 \}$$ to get the right answer.